# How to connect to IBM Websphere MQ present on server through UFT?

Tags: ibm-mq, hp-uft

We have to connect to IBM WebSphere MQ present on remote server through UFT 14.02v which is present on desktop. Here we are using API Test under UFT to test WebSphere MQ.
While trying to connect following error message getting displayed: "To run tests with IBM’s MQ client, make sure to install the MQ client on all machines running these tests".

Do we need to install MQ client on desktop(where UFT is installed)? or lets know the better approach to connect WebSphere MQ through UFT(API test)

Comment: Yes you would need to have IBM MQ installed on the machine that is making the connection.  Does UTF use JMS API to connect?  If so you can download the v9 Java-All package which includes all the jar files required in a self-extracting jar file, much lighter than a full MQ client install.

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc..Does UTF use JMS API to connect? Yes.